# E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)--Logcat error in android Studio

Tags: android, android-logcat

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("TAG","test");
    }
}
```

I want to see the log in the project, and then the following exception occurred

```
01-19 19:35:09.128 20144-20144/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.wjc.rhr.demo02/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.wjc.rhr.demo02/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex) with checksum 0xe4501e4d in OatFile /data/data/com.wjc.rhr.demo02/cache/slice-slice_6-classes.dex
01-19 19:35:09.618 20144-20144/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-19 19:35:09.877 20144-20144/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1163fc15 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
01-19 19:35:09.895 20144-20144/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{2a0528f5 com.wjc.rhr.demo02/com.wjc.rhr.demo02.MainActivity,ident = 0}
01-19 19:35:09.903 20144-20144/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{2a0528f5 com.wjc.rhr.demo02/com.wjc.rhr.demo02.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1163fc15 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
01-19 19:35:09.948 20144-20187/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
01-19 19:35:10.035 20144-20187/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 E/libPowerStretch: LUCID_1 (1484825710035) PowerXtend Common Architecture Integration Call - libinput.so
01-19 19:35:11.956 20144-20188/com.wjc.rhr.demo02 E/libGameXtend: LUCID_1 (1484825711956) PowerXtend identified application start. Package name: com.wjc.rhr.demo02. Application is handled by GameXtend
, err(0)
```

Comment: This may be use full to some one https://stackoverflow.com/a/67215432/2795035