# Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Tags: android, logging, buffer, logcat

I have a big problem with all my Android Project which is the **error** :

`"Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)"`.

I don't really know what to do and how can I fix it. Can anyone help me please ?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Find `Advanced logging` in your phone's `Developer options` setting entry.
Set to **Allow all**.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not available  in my cell
oppo f1s

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but it may use full to someone.
In my case: Go to Settings -> System -> Developer Options ->

1. Scroll till you see "Logging level" (Click and set it to verbose).
2. and also scroll to "Always show crash dialogue" and enable it.